# Write jmeter script in non-GUI mode

Tags: jmeter

For my project I am required to write jmeter test plan from the command line in a non-interactive mode and save the result to file and then export it to mysql database.

Any idea how to go about?

Comment: http://blogs.amd.com/developer/2009/03/31/using-apache-jmeter-in-non-gui-mode/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You usually don't write script in non gui mode.

You run them in non gui mode.

Save them as CSV and inject data after load test in a database using manually written code or some load tool oracle or other db propose.

Comment: thank you i figured that out. my problem now is how to test 100 different website using jmeter. any idea?